# Java Array remove last stored element

Tags: java, arrays

In my program, I have 2 array (x,y) that stores value taken from the user.
When a negative value is entered, the program should stop asking for new values.
Until here everything works fine. However, the negative value should not be stored in the array. Unfortunately, my array stores negative values too. How could I change the program to make sure negative values are not stored?

```
for (int i = 1, x = 0,y = 0; i <= 2*maxPoints; i++){

    System.out.print("Enter the number: ");
    double value = keys.nextDouble();

    if (i%2==1){
        xVal[x]=value;
        x++;
    }
    else if (i%2==0){
        yVal[y]=value;
        y++;
        numPoints++;
    }

    if (value <= 0 ){
        break;
    }
}
```

I tried to use ArrayUtils.remove() but it does not work.

The output is like this:

```
Enter the number: 1
Enter the number: 2
Enter the number: 3
Enter the number: -4
we have 2 Points 
Point 1 is: (1.0 ,2.0)
Point 2 is: (3.0 ,-4.0)
```

The last number is negative, therefore the program should only display Point 1.

Comment: move your `if(value<=0)` to before your other if statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to check if value is less than 0 before you store it in the array. Then just move this

```
 if (value <= 0 ){
     break;
 }
```

above, here

```
System.out.print("Enter the number: ");
double value = keys.nextDouble();
if (value <= 0 ){
    break;
}
```